# Sql Server replication or mirroring

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, database-mirroring

What are the typical scenarios when Replication is recommended to use ?
What are the typical scenarios when Mirroring is recommended to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few types of replication, transactional replication (probably the most commonly used form) is typically used when you need to send a subset of data from one server to another, such as sending data from a production server to a reporting database etc

A quote from technet about replication:

> Transactional replication is typically used in server-to-server scenarios that require high throughput, including: improving scalability and availability; data warehousing and reporting; integrating data from multiple sites; integrating heterogeneous data; and offloading batch processing. Merge replication is primarily designed for mobile applications or distributed server applications that have possible data conflicts. Common scenarios include: exchanging data with mobile users; consumer point of sale (POS) applications; and integration of data from multiple sites. Snapshot replication is used to provide the initial data set for transactional and merge replication; it can also be used when complete refreshes of data are appropriate. With these three types of replication, SQL Server provides a powerful and flexible system for synchronizing data across your enterprise.

Mirroring on the other hand is a high availability feature where the whole database is mirrored to another server to guard against failure, however, it is not recommended to use mirroring in any new development as it is now a deprecated feature (as of SQL Server 2012) and will be removed in a future version.  AlwaysOn availability groups are the replacement for mirroring.